# Excluded a contactus aspx page from web project but still receiving emails?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We had a html page that was using an ASPX page to submit the email to our email server.  We have been getting 99% junk, so I was turning off the submission form.  Commented out the code on the html page and excluded the aspx page that processed the submit and sent the email.  But I am still getting the emails?  How is that possible?  Am I missing something?  How are people still submitting stuff?  Cached versions of the website out there somewhere on other proxy servers?

Commented out the form on the html page
excluded the aspx page from the project - published the website

N/A - all related code has been commented out or removed from the project.

Thought these steps would stop the garbage emails from our contact us web page - but they are still coming in.

Comment: You would need to actually nuke the temporary asp.net files on the server; quite likely it wasn't nuked when you did a fresh deploy?

Comment: depends on which version of windows: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=rQpkXezBFMWC5wLIp6f4Aw&q=temporary+asp.net+files+location&oq=temporary+asp.net+files+location&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30l9.614.7507..7861...3.0..1.421.2920.33j3-1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j33i299.XO8FcTq-SWM&ved=0ahUKEwiszK2f_KDkAhVFwVkKHcjTCT8Q4dUDCAc&uact=5&safe=active&ssui=on also make sure you recycle your app pool.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I knew it had to be cached somewhere - forgot about temp asp files.

Comment: Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: it still seems i am getting some - there is still a DLL in the bin directory in the website IIS folder - App_Web_contactussubmit.aspx.2864eb60.dll

Comment: Delete it and see what happens.

Comment: If I were you, I would have added a Redirect call on page load or pre-load to be extra sure that nobody lands here. Otherwise, deleting the code that you don't mean to use in future is perfectly fine.

Comment: Moreover, to avoid junk mails, You should add a captcha to every form submission so people can do a bit effort before junking anyone.

Comment: Once I deleted the DLLs I found in the bin directory (actually 2 versions there) they stopped coming through.  Thanks for the help George!